# Render a surface transparent only if directly visible

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I want to render some glass, in order to actually see something it requires a background. However I want the glass object to have a transparent surrounding. How do I make a background which is considered by the refraction of the glass but is transparent when it is seen directly by the camera?

Comment: I'm not  sure if this is possible in BI, but it's pretty easy in cycles.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a solution for BI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using blender internal, for the material of the objects you want to disappear, turn on transparency and choose mask with an alpha of 0.0.

[image]

The transparent objects will still show in reflections but not be seen in the camera.

[image]

Comment: Note that if there are objects behind the mask object, they will be replaced with sky.

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: I should add that for this to work in the `Options` category of the material `Traceable` must be checked.